# Error in Arima, on output of certain orders

Tags: r, arima

I have a time-series dataset, named "datats"

```
Arima(datats, order=c(0,1,1), seasonal = c(2,1,1))
```

This gives output

```
Arima(datats, order=c(2,1,1), seasonal = c(2,1,1))
```

This gives output
But

```
Arima(datats, order=c(1,1,1), seasonal = c(2,1,1))
```

This doesn't
It shows error:
"Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  :
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite"
Why it is happening? How can I solve it

Comment: Try [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-February/425777.html) `optim.method="Nelder-Mead"`

Comment: where do you put this code? I used code Arima(datats, order=c(1,1,1), seasonal = c(2,1,Q1, optim.method="Nelder-Mead") , but it shows same error

Comment: I think your code is wrong, a parenthesis is missing and `Q1`. `Arima(datats, order=c(1,1,1), seasonal = c(2,1,1), optim.method="Nelder-Mead")`